# apply function on each row of the dataframe and return a dataframe

Tags: r, nlp

I want to use jiebar to segment some Chinese sentences, these sentences are stored in a data frame.One way to do it is to convert the data frame into a list, then use apply_list.

```
library(jiebar)
mixseg = worker()
c <- apply_list(as.list(weibo$weibo), mixseg)
```

dataset: weibo$weibo

```
[1] "诸丽娜Kitty 打卡第天运动只为更好的自己运动就是坚持快来加入打卡社区吧"                
[2] "今天的高尔夫球课高尔夫️教练可是全美排名前的教练哦\U0001f3cc AmericanNew Jersey Hudson"
[3] "鼓掌鼓掌第一次滑雪居然是在美国体验在雪上的激情与速度过瘾酷 Mount Peter"              
[4] "伪装幸福学着让自己更坚强  我正在使用假面女孩封面图好漂亮你们都快来试试封面图预览"    
[5] "抢到啦大家元宵节快乐顺心如意鲜花鲜花 AmericanNew York Queens"                        
[6] " Happy Chinese New Year 美国City of New York Central Park Conservancy"
```

However, the size of the return list is 3 times larger than the original dataset if I do it in this way. Therefore, I want to use ldply/laply to return the result as a data frame, but I encounter this error

```
b<- ldply(weibo2, segment(mixseg))
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  argument "jiebar" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: have you checked [rowwise()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/rowwise) ?

Comment: please increase the reproducibility of your work. it's very hard to tell what's going wrong when we don't have any idea what `weibo2` is